# Need some help troubleshooting this assignment

Tags: java

I know you guys arent here to do my homework for me but I just cant seem to get this to work. I receive an error in class MPhRunner stating that the constructor in class MilesPerHour cannot be applied to given types. I guess I just don't understand what that means.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MPHRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
        int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
        int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
        int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

        MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour();
        test.setNums(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.calcMPH();
        test.print();
        }
}


import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class MilesPerHour
{
    private int distance, hours, minutes;
    private double mph;
    MPHRunner one= new MPHRunner();

    public MilesPerHour(int dist ,int hrs,int mins)
    {
        setNums(dist,hrs,mins);
        mph=0.0;
    }
    public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int  mins)
    {
        minutes=mins;
        hours=hrs;
        distance=dist;
    }


    public void calcMPH()
    {
        mph= distance /(hours*60+minutes)/60;
    }

    public void print()
    {System.out.print("Your speed is"+mph);
    }
}
```

Comment: @tnw make an answer out of that

Comment: there should be quite a big red line in your ide, if you're using one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor for MilesPerHour takes 3 arguments... you give it none! Try:

```
MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins);
```

... and remove the following line (it's redundant since the constructor already does that):

```
test.setNums(dist, hrs, mins);
```

Comment: Yes, you can only invoke the no-argument constructor if you don't have another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class MPHRunner
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

        out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
        int dist = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
        int hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

        out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
        int mins = keyboard.nextInt();

        MilesPerHour test = new MilesPerHour(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.setNums(dist, hrs, mins);
        test.calcMPH();
        test.print();
        }
}

 class MilesPerHour
{
    private int distance, hours, minutes;
    private double mph;
    MPHRunner one= new MPHRunner();

    public MilesPerHour(int dist ,int hrs,int mins)
    {
        setNums(dist,hrs,mins);
        mph=0.0;
    }
    public void setNums(int dist, int hrs, int  mins)
    {
        minutes=mins;
        hours=hrs;
        distance=dist;
    }


    public void calcMPH()
    {
        mph= distance /(hours*60+minutes)/60;
    }

    public void print()
    {System.out.print("Your speed is"+mph);
    }
}
```

I modified your code and its working fine.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor have the same name as the class.

class MilesPerHour

public MilesPerHour <-- constructor

Also for methods you can create a constructor with arguments.

like

public MilesPerHour(int dist ,int hrs,int mins)

If you like to use MilesPerHour, then use as `MilesPerHour milePerHour = new MilesPerHour(dis, hrs, mins);`